# Ranking values with repeats. Matlab

Tags: matlab, rank

My question is simple, but I can't find the answer...

I have a 100,000 rows x 30 colums matrix for a simulation, and I need to rank the 100k values of each column.
I'm looking for something similar to `tiedrank` but I need that repeats does count (and not the average).

Suppose: `data = [-1 2 0 -2 0]` what I need is `rank= [2 5 3 1 4]`

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Juan

Comment: why `-1` is ranked `-2` ?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! It should be 2... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need `sort`:

```
data = [-1 2 0 -2 0];
[ignore, idx] = sort( data );
rank( idx ) = 1:numel(idx)

rank =

    2     5     3     1     4
```

To rank all columns of matrix as once you can use the following code

```
data = [ -1 2 0 -2 0; -1 -1 -2 2 2]' ; %'
[n m] = size( data ); % number of rows and columns
[ignore idx] = sort(data); % sort columns
rank = zeros( size(data) ); % allocate
rank( sub2ind( size(rank), idx, bsxfun(@times, 1:m, ones(n,1) ) ) ) = ...
    repmat( (1:n)', 1, m )

rank =

     2     2
     5     3
     3     1
     1     4
     4     5
```

Comment: @user2431026 please see my edit - extending the solution for ranking several columns

Comment: Fantastic! You were very helpful!